# Angular 2 $this.parent().next().show() on click

Tags: angular

I have a list of items. Each row in the list displays name, date, etc. Beneath each row is another element `.panel` that should only display when the 'expand' element is clicked. This is what I have so far.

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div>
    <div>{{item...}}</div>
    <div (click)="showPanel(item.id)>expand</div>
    <div>{{item...}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel' *ngIf="showMe">returned info from server</div>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
showMe: string = false;

showPanel(id:number){
  this.showMe = true;
  //get additional detail from server
}
```

Upon click ALL `.panel` elements will show, I only want the one that's directly below the row to show.  In jquery I would do this upon click:

```
$this.parent().next().show();
```

Is there any way to do something similar in angular2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing, that way every  **`ngIf`** will work so all elements will be shown or hidden at a same time.

Just add appropriate property(object property) to show & hide element.

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/h4TYyiFwhoZBej0sUXDK?p=preview**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <div>
    <div>{{item...}}</div>
    <div (click)="item.showMe=!item.showMe">expand</div>  //<<<###here
    <div>{{item...}}</div>
  </div>
  <div class='panel' *ngIf="item.showMe">returned info from server</div>  //<<<### here
</div>
```

---

With click event by passing an object as a whole,

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
      <div>
        <div>{{item...}}</div>
        <div (click)="showPanel(item)">expand</div>  //<<<###here
        <div>{{item...}}</div>
      </div>
      <div class='panel' *ngIf="item.showMe">returned info from server</div>  //<<<### here
    </div>


showPanel(item){
    item.showMe=!item.showMe;
    // do whatever you want to do.
}
```

Comment: This works but what if I want to pass `item.id` to the `showPanel(item.id)` method on the click event?

Comment: As shown,  you don't need typescript function. I mean don't need to cal any `showPanel` function at all. It handles it in HTML itself. I updated plunker.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but my index API is responding with a limited set of data, when I click to expand I want to get the FULL set of data for the item AND it's associated models.  This could be an image of the item along with other associated data from the API backend, hence hitting the `show` action separately

Comment: IF you are using MODEL then make sure you add `showMe` property with default value to false. I partially understand your problem not fully. But let me show you how you can do it using function too. updating answer.

Comment: Ok, that works great ... thanks, just getting to grips with angular2 now.  One last thing, how would I make the show panel exclusive? i.e. when you click to expand the second one the first one disappears?

Answer (score 2):

You're completelyignoring the ID passed to the showPanel() method. Don't. Instead of using a global boolean used by each item, store the ID of the item to show (if only one mustbe shown), or change a boolean property of the expanded item (if several items can be expanded at the same time).

```
showPanel(item) {
  this.expandedPanel = panel;

  // or, if multiple panels can be expanded:
  // item.expanded = true;
}
```

In the view, use

```
*ngIf="item === expandedItem"
```

or

```
*ngIf="item.expanded"
```